# Python / Pandas - What is the best way to extract a Dict or Tuple of a DataFrame.columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Is there a built-in pandas method to create a dict or tuple of a 'DataFrame.columns'?
I want to map the column-index with their values as seen below.
I am currently achieving this by enumerating the return of df.columns()

Is there a better way?

**Code**
`df = pd.DataFrame('x', columns=list('ABCDE'), index=range(3))`
`tuple(enumerate(df.columns))`
`dict(enumerate(df.columns))`

**Output:**
((0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (4, 'E'))

```
 {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}
```

Comment: These both seem like exactly the right ways to achieve this. Is there a problem with them?

Comment: @DTM I don't think so, you solution is quick a compact, I don't see any value for other solution

Comment: @jprebys - No problem.  I thought I saw a pandas built-in function the other day that might be more efficient, but can't find it anymore.  Sounds like enumerate is the way to go - Thx